# Определить, можно ли получить число N используя операции: +, -, *, / и скобки?

Tags: алгоритм

Есть числа a, b, c, d. Нужно определить можно ли получить число 24 из них, используя операции: +, -, *, / и скобки. 
Ничего кроме полного вбивания вручную всех комбинаций не придумал, но уверен есть способ проще.

Comment: Проще - автоматическое вбивание всех комбинаций :) В данном случае это всего лишь 64 варианта..

Comment: Kromster, в той задаче числа даны изначально, в этой нет.

Comment: А какая разница?

Answer (score 0):

Моё решение на C++:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int a, b, c, d;
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;

    // ((a 'i' b) 'j' c) 'k' d
    //0 == +, 1 == +, 2 == *, 4 == /
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        int resI;
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0: resI = a + b; break;
            case 1: resI = a - b; break;
            case 2: resI = a * b; break;
            case 3: resI = a / b; break;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            int resJ = resI;
            switch (j)
            {
                case 0: resJ += c; break;
                case 1: resJ -= c; break;
                case 2: resJ *= c; break;
                case 3: resJ /= c; break;
            }

            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
            {
                int resK = resJ;
                switch (k)
                {
                    case 0: resK += d; break;
                    case 1: resK -= d; break;
                    case 2: resK *= d; break;
                    case 3: resK /= d; break;
                }

                if (resK == 24)
                {
                    cout << "Yes";
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    cout << "No";
    return 0;
}
```